# Spring Data DynamoDB NoSuchMethodException on everything except save

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb, spring-data

The service is using a DynamoDB with Spring Data. Database access, object mapping etc. all work without errors, I can save objects in the database as expected.

My problem is that no method except the `save` method seems to be working on Spring Data Repositories. I can't use `deleteAll`, I can't use `findById`, I can't use any custom method like `findByField`. They all throw a NoSuchMethodException.

I have the following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.11</version>
</parent>
....
<dependencies>
...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.boostchicken</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.749</version>
  </dependency>
</depdencencies>
```

This is the data class (in Kotlin)

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBIndexHashKey
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverted
import org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.EnableScan
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
...

@DynamoDBTable
data class MyEntity(
    @field:DynamoDBHashKey
    @field:DynamoDBAttribute
    val id: String,
    ... some other fields that get persisted as expected
)

@EnableScan
interface MyEntityRepository : CrudRepository<MyEntity, String>
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
val ent = MyEntity(
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
        ... some other fields
    )
//this line works exactly as expected
myEntityRepository.save(ent)
//this line crashes (see stack trace below)
myEntityRepository.findById(ent.id)
```

I already tried various different other dependencies: all versions > 5.2.0 from boostchicken, also the more popular `derjust` dependency which is also part of the baeldung tutorial but when not using boostchicken I always get the error that no repository is found (`found 0 dynamodb interfaces`) and the repository is not found at all. With boostchicken that is not a problem and again saving and mapping all works flawlessly, but no queries are possible. I also tried different Repositories, the `CrudRepository`, `PaginationAndSortingRepository` etc. but they all deliver the same result.

This is the stackTrace I get with the above code (the exception is thrown in the line where `findById` is called:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: mypackagemigration.MyEntity.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:626)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.lang.InstantiationException: mypackagemigration.MyEntity
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:639)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$DeclaringReflect.newInstance(StandardBeanProperties.java:183)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: could not instantiate class mypackagemigration.MyEntity
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$DeclaringReflect.newInstance(StandardBeanProperties.java:185)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:261)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.privateMarshallIntoObject(DynamoDBMapper.java:472)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.marshallIntoObjects(DynamoDBMapper.java:500)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.PaginatedScanList.<init>(PaginatedScanList.java:64)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.scan(DynamoDBMapper.java:1571)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.scan(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:236)
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.core.DynamoDBTemplate.scan(DynamoDBTemplate.java:128)
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.SimpleDynamoDBCrudRepository.findAll(SimpleDynamoDBCrudRepository.java:160)
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.SimpleDynamoDBCrudRepository.deleteAll(SimpleDynamoDBCrudRepository.java:203)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at 

org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy158.deleteAll(Unknown Source)
    at mypackagemigration.MyEntityService.test(MyEntityService.kt:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
    ... 18 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of trial-and-error and scouring the internet for working examples I finally managed to fix the bug. I do not know the exact cause yet but the problem is caused by using a data-class with val in kotlin.

When changing the entity to this, the code suddenly works, findAll and other methods can be used as expected:

```
@DynamoDBTable
class MyEntity {
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    var id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
}
```

Here again the version of the entity that didn't work, for direct comparision:

```
@DynamoDBTable
data class MyEntity(
    @field:DynamoDBHashKey
    @field:DynamoDBAttribute
    val id: String,
)
```